# Dividing the value of 2 columns in spark dataframe

Tags: java, apache-spark

[image: The table looks like this]

I have this table in Spark stored as Dataframe. I want to get another dataframe(url,url1,ratio) which contains the ratio,where ratio = count1/count in it. How to write the operation for it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
import spark.implicits._
val newDF = df.withColumn("ratio", $"count1" / $"count")
```

this line of code will add a column named `ration` to your `df` and store the result in `newDF`

**EDIT 1 : (Solution In Java as requested)**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
Dataset<Row> newDF = df.withColumn("ration", col("count1").divide(col("count")))
```

Comment: In java,my friend

Comment: Just edited the answer, if it's correct please make it as the recommended one. @user3366497

Comment: @HarounMohammedi How can you do the same in `pyspark`

Comment: How can I perform other calculations like `1 + log(<col1>)*log(100/<col2>)` and store it in a new column or may be store it in an existing column?

Comment: @VipulSharma take a look at `org.apache.spark.sql.functions` there are a lot of functions that could help you achieve what you want

Answer (score 1):

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;
Dataset<Row> newDs = oldDs.withColumn("ratio",col("count1").divide(col("count")))
```

*N.B. For Arithmetic Exception or NAN then spark 2.0 safely makes the result as null*